# Audit tables on Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to get statistics on a table in Redshift like the way we can get on a dataframe in python by using df.describe() as follows-

+-------+---------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|summary|           col 1           |      col2       |col3                  |           col4     |col5           |
+-------+---------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|  count|                      26716|              869|                 26716|               26716|          26716|
|   mean|                        0.0|          49409.0|                  null|                null|           null|
| stddev|                        0.0|24096.28685088223|                  null|                null|           null|
|    min|                          0|             7745|  pqr                 |xyz                 |abcd  |
|    max|                          0|            91073|  pqr                 |xyz                 |abcd           |
+-------+---------------------------+-----------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------+

I have a use case to run statistics like above on tables in Redshift on regular basis. I can get column names and data types for a table from PG_TABLE_DEF and I am looking to run Redshift in-built functions such as min(), max(), count(), mean() etc. over the columns identified from the table. Not sure if this is the right approach but if there is a better approach, please share your thoughts.